# Are there any implications of setting the Availability Group FailoverPeriod in FCM to zero?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

In Failover Cluster Manager, in the Failover tab of the Availability Group Properties, the Availability Group default value for FailoverPeriod is 6 hours.

1. What is the best value for this setting?
2. Is there any issue with setting the value to zero?
   i.e Maximum failures in the specified period = 1
   Period (hours) = 0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mscs/groups-failoverthreshold):

> If the Cluster service exceeds the number of failover attempts specified by FailoverThreshold within the time interval specified by FailoverPeriod, it stops trying to fail over the group.

Setting the FailoverPeriod to 0 means the Cluster will never failover automatically once the number of FailoverThreshold failovers occurs.

These parameters are designed to prevent flapping, where a problem causes the cluster to failover over and over.

Comment: thank you for your response and your time, much appreciated. I am still working on this. However, I can confirm that when the failover period was left at the default 6 hours (and threshold of 1), I did not get a failback in that time period. It was only a failover in one direction that I could get. When however, I changed the failover period to 0 (threshold still 1), I am able to get failover and failback in both directions. I would just like to know if leaving the failover period at 0 has any negative implications. Thank you again.